# suddenly .htaccess redirect loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This .htaccess was working, until I accidently changed it to the 2nd code clipping. When I reversed the git pull, suddenly my original .htaccess gets me internal server errors... apache2 service restart doesn't help.
Why? And how to fix?? Please help!!!

My rewriterules should

- remove www
- redirect ip address to website
- redirect blog.mywebsite.be to mywebsite.be/subdom/blog without showing it has redirected.
- same with test

**ORIGINAL**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 403 /ErrorPages/403-error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorPages/404-error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /ErrorPages/500-error.html
ErrorDocument 502 /ErrorPages/502-error.html
ErrorDocument 503 /ErrorPages/503-error.html
ErrorDocument 504 /ErrorPages/504-error.html

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.be
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.be/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xxx #anonymized ip address
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.be/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mywebsite\.be
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdom/blog/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mywebsite\.be
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdom/blog/$1 [L]
```

**ACCIDENTLY CHANGED TO**

```
RewriteEngine on


# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

**apache2 error.log**

```
[Thu Feb 09 20:54:33.186492 2017] [core:error] [pid 888] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://blog.mywebsite.be/login
```

Comment: What do you mean by *accidentally changed*? Rules look totally different now. Also I am not seeing `redirect blog.mywebsite.be to mywebsite.be/subdom/blog without showing it has redirected` requirement being met anywhere.